# syntax error in python files when running buildozer to convert kivy project into apk

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to convert my kivy-python code into an apk file . the deployment running process goes well and produce a non working apk application.
I noticed some errors in log file :

```
€ = 2
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifie


from __future__ import print_function
                                        ^
SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

my enviroment is linux ubuntu,python 3,kivy 1.11.1
any suggestions please.

Comment: Have you tried fixing the errors that you mentioned?

Comment: change `€ = ...` to `another_name = ...`

Comment: thanks for response. I will try but  what about __future__ errors

Comment: The error message tells you how to correct the `__future__` import.